# Why is my program skipping my switch statement, going straight to default?

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to programming and am trying to write a simple ATM type program. I have a function that takes the option input by the user and a function that manages the input given called 'operate till' which uses a switch statement to filter through the given input. For some reason its skipping straight to default and I've no idea why, knowing me I'm probably dumb and have forgotten to put something in.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    float currentbalance; //set basic variable

    float setStudentAccount(float &initBalance); //signature
    setStudentAccount(currentbalance); //call

    void enterOption(float &currentbalance);
    enterOption(currentbalance);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

float setStudentAccount(float &initBalance ) {
    initBalance = 20;
    return initBalance;
}

void enterOption(float &currentbalance) {
    char choice;

    cout << "\nOPTIONS:\nW for withdrawal.\nC for credit.\nB for balance\nE for exit.\n" << endl; 
    cout << "Enter your choice:"; 
    cin >> choice; 

    //char(tolower(choice));// convert character to lowercase

    char operateTill(char command, float &currentbalance);
    operateTill(choice, currentbalance);
}

char operateTill(char command, float &currentbalance) {
    
    switch (command)
    {
    case 1: if (command == 'b')
    {
        void displayBalance(float &currentbalance);
        displayBalance(currentbalance);
    }
            break;
    case 2: if (command == 'w')
    {
        float Withdraw(float &accountbal);
        float Withdraw();
    }
            break;
    case 3: if (command == 'c')
    {
        float Credit(float &currentbalance);
        Credit(currentbalance);
    }
            break;
    default: cout << "\nChoose a valid option." << endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void displayBalance(float &currentbalance) {
    cout << "\nYour balance is...\t" << currentbalance;
}

float Withdraw(float &currentbalance) {
    float debitAmount;
    cout << "\nEnter amount to be withdrawn...";
    cin >> debitAmount;
    currentbalance = currentbalance - debitAmount;
    cout << "\nYour balance is now...\t" << currentbalance;
    return currentbalance;
    return 0;
}

float Credit(float &currentbalance) {
    float creditAmount;
    cout << "\nEnter amount to be credited...";
    cin >> creditAmount;
    currentbalance = currentbalance + creditAmount;
    cout << "\nYour balance is now...\t" << currentbalance;
    return currentbalance;
}
```

Comment: How can `command` be both `1` and `'b'` at the same time? How does a user even input the character value 1 in your application?

Comment: `float Withdraw(float &accountbal); float Withdraw();` looks strange. Why not call `Withdraw` like other parts of your program?

Comment: Oh I see what I've done, I haven't really used switch statements much before,I guess changing the 'case 1' to 'case b' would be a solution.

Comment: It is very rare to to declare functions immediately before using them. Most people put all of the function declarations at the top of the file.

Comment: @MikeCAT I haven't finished doing the parameters yet if thats what you mean looks strange, if youre talking about how ive set it out i thought you had to declare or write the signature for the function before calling it?just because ive written the 'withdraw' function further down the page

Comment: @molbdnilo right i didn't know that, noted thanks.

Comment: @JoeTakac You are declareing functions and calling functions after that in other parts of your program. This is OK (but usually declarations are done before definition of function). In this part you are declareing the function `Withdraw` twice without calling this function. Thks looks strange because the declarations are meaningless since they are not used.

Comment: @MikeCAT oh i see what you're talking about now, yeah that was just a mistake I didn't amend before asking the question on here, thanks anyway.

Comment: Once code execution  hits a return the function is done executing. The second return after the first in `Withdraw()` is pointless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code

```
    switch (command)
    {
    case 1: if (command == 'b')
    {
        void displayBalance(float &currentbalance);
        displayBalance(currentbalance);
    }
            break;
    case 2: if (command == 'w')
    {
        float Withdraw(float &accountbal);
        float Withdraw();
    }
            break;
    case 3: if (command == 'c')
    {
        float Credit(float &currentbalance);
        Credit(currentbalance);
    }
            break;
    default: cout << "\nChoose a valid option." << endl;
        break;
    }
```

You are checking `command` against the numbers `1`, `2`, and `3` and not the numbers `'b'`, `'w'`, and `'c'` because the `if` statements are after `case`s and they won't be executed unless `command` is equal to the corresponding numbers.

What you want should be:

```
    switch (command)
    {
    case 'b':
    {
        void displayBalance(float &currentbalance);
        displayBalance(currentbalance);
    }
            break;
    case 'w':
    {
        float Withdraw(float &accountbal);
        float Withdraw();
    }
            break;
    case 'c':
    {
        float Credit(float &currentbalance);
        Credit(currentbalance);
    }
            break;
    default: cout << "\nChoose a valid option." << endl;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing in switch case is that comparing command with 1,2.. as cases and then a if(...) statement.
so if you input 1 then case 1 will be executed, if(...) statement will evaluate false as it is not equal to 'b' simultaneously and ultimately default case will execute.

solution- remove if(...) condition and use case 'b': or case 66: here 66 is ascii of 'b'